# Is it possible to use Azure functions to run network commands like traceroute, or tcpdump?

Tags: azure-functions

Hi I am new to Azure Cloud and scripting - Is it possible to use Azure funtions to run network commands like traceroute, or tcpdump in order to trouble shoot network issues with our wan connection ?

Comment: This question should be closed as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45348498/run-exe-executable-file-in-azure-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to run the commands (identical to the way you’d do it from a console app), but keep in mind that Azure Functions runs within the App Service sandbox and some operations may be restricted. You can find more information about the sandbox here: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox