# Bundling command-line tool in azure functions using visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, azure-functions

I have to integrate a third-party command-line tool within existing azure functions. I saw a couple of questions (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45348498/run-exe-executable-file-in-azure-function)) and blogs with example how can we call exe from azure functions by uploading exe file from the azure portal and execute from code.

**Is uploading from portal is the only way of uploading exe?** Problem with this approach is that I need manually upload the file after every time I deploy code from visual studio because all files are beeing removed. Is there any way I can simply keep it unchanged or make it part of my project so the exe and its dependency files (not assemblies but internal files it references) or is there a way I can automate this to copy/upload to azure functions.

I am using App Service plan instead of consumption plan which I understand has some flexibility and control over the host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Azure Pipeline, you could simply copy any files you need along with your function app before archiving the publish folder.

For example, if you are following the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-azure-devops#net), you could copy the files you need to the publish directory (or even run a script if you need to fetch them from somewhere) before the `ArchiveFiles@2` task.

Building on top of the sample azure pipeline in the docs, something like this should do

```
pool:
      vmImage: 'VS2017-Win2016'
steps:
- script: |
    dotnet restore
    dotnet build --configuration Release
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: publish
    arguments: '--configuration Release --output publish_output'
    projects: '*.csproj'
    publishWebProjects: false
    modifyOutputPath: true
    zipAfterPublish: false
- task: ShellScript@2
  inputs:
    scriptPath: 'fetch-3rd-party-files.sh'
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: "Archive files"
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/publish_output"
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveFile: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build$(Build.BuildId).zip"
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    name: 'drop'
```

**Also,** if required, you could directly integrate the copy task in your `csproj` file as well. Something like this should do (refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44378406/10417839) for more details)

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  ...
  <Target Name="CopyFiles" AfterTargets="Publish">
    <Copy 
      SourceFiles="random.dat"
      DestinationFolder="$(PublishDir)\data_files\"
    />
  </Target>
  ...
</Project>
```

Check the [reference to the Copy Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/copy-task?view=vs-2019) used above for available options.