# Azure function .elf file - permission denied

Tags: linux, azure, function, azure-functions, permission-denied

I have a problem with my Azure Functions App on Linux. I create a simple .NET function for Azure Function Linux. In that function I try to run a simple compiled app created in C++. I saw in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45348498/run-exe-executable-file-in-azure-function) that someone could run a .exe file on Azure Function Windows. I tried it and it works.

My Function ran a .exe file and returned content from them. So I try to do the same thing, but on Azure Functions Linux. When I'm trying to run a compiled file, the Function returns an exception with message "Permission denied".

I used the same code as in the link and I created a function in VS 2019 because I can't do it from the Azure Portal.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. In its current form, this question is no fit for SO. Could you explain a bit better what you're trying to do, what you tried and where you failed? Please refer to [ask]. On-topic: Azure Functions run on a sandbox, so running executable-like will not be a simple feat.

Comment: Hello and sorry, I updated the post with new information.

Comment: There could be a couple of things causing this. For one: what type of compiled app is it? Does it try to access (system) resources it doesn't have access to? Is the error thrown in the Function code or in the compiled app?

Comment: The compiled application is very simple, it adds the two received numbers. The error was reported in the function code.

Comment: By any chance have you gone through this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-function-app-linux-app-service-plan

Answer (score 0):

Created the timer trigger function in the function app and  After that, I uploaded `.exe` file in the `Code+Test` Environment of Timer Trigger Function.

**function.json**

```
{  
"bindings": [  
{  
"name": "myTimer",  
"type": "timerTrigger",  
"direction": "in",  
"schedule": "0 */1 * * * *"  
}  
],  
"disabled": false  
}
```

I have followed this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45348498/run-exe-executable-file-in-azure-function) to insert the code in `run.csx` file for running `.exe` file in function application and the execution is succeeded.

[image: ![enter image description here](https://imgur.com/jiwnWdW)]

After installing the `.exe` file open the Kudo console and type the below command so that you can read the elf files from there you can check the required attributes

```
readelf
```

[image]

if you want to get the version of elf file use readelf -v
[image]