# Automating running Python code using Azure services

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

Hi everyone on Stackoverflow,

I wrote two python scripts. One script is for picking up local files and sending them to GCS (Google Cloud Storage). Another one is opposite - for taking files from GCS that were uploaded and saving locally.

I want to automate process using Azure.

What would you recommend to use? Azure Function App, Azure Logic App or other services?

*
I'm now trying to use Logic App. I made .exe file using pyinstaller and looking for connector in Logic App that will run my program (.exe file). I have trigger in Logic App - "When a file is added or modified", but now I stack when selecting next step (connector)..

Kind regards,
Anna

Adding code as requested:

```
from google.cloud import storage
import os
import glob
import json

    # Finding path to config file that is called "gcs_config.json" in directory C:/
    def find_config(name, path):
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
            if name in files:
                return os.path.join(root, name)
    
    def upload_files(config_file):
        # Reading 3 Parameters for upload from JSON file
        with open(config_file, "r") as file:
            contents = json.loads(file.read())
            print(contents)
    
        # Setting up login credentials
        os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = contents['login_credentials']
        # The ID of GCS bucket
        bucket_name = contents['bucket_name']
        # Setting path to files
        LOCAL_PATH = contents['folder_from']
    
        for source_file_name in glob.glob(LOCAL_PATH + '/**'):
    
        # For multiple files upload
        # Setting destination folder according to file name 
            if os.path.isfile(source_file_name):
                partitioned_file_name = os.path.split(source_file_name)[-1].partition("-")
                file_type_name = partitioned_file_name[0]
    
                # Setting folder where files will be uploaded
                destination_blob_name = file_type_name + "/" + os.path.split(source_file_name)[-1]
    
                # Setting up required variables for GCS 
                storage_client = storage.Client()
                bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
                blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)
    
                # Running upload and printing confirmation message
                blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)
                print("File from {} uploaded to {} in bucket {}.".format(
                    source_file_name, destination_blob_name, bucket_name
                ))
    
    config_file = find_config("gcs_config.json", "C:/")
    
    upload_files(config_file)
```

config.json:

```
{
"login_credentials": "C:/Users/AS/Downloads/bright-velocity-___-53840b2f9bb4.json",
"bucket_name": "staging.bright-velocity-___.appspot.com",
"folder_from": "C:/Users/AS/Documents/Test2/",
"folder_for_downloaded_files": "C:/Users/AnnaShepilova/Documents/DownloadedFromGCS2/",

"given_date": "",
"given_prefix": ["Customer", "Account"] }
```

Comment: I connected to GCS ok using Python (credentials json and I use "google" library). Now I need to run Python script

Comment: Added code, but I made standalone program from it (.exe) I want to run UploadToGCS.exe using Azure LogicApp

Comment: Sorry, took time to format as code

Comment: Added a bit more now to include config file

Comment: you talk about azure, so if you have a virtual machine in azure, you can certainly setup croj jobs to automate the process.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is **no built-in connector** in `Logic Apps` for interacting with **Google Cloud Services**. however, you can use [Google Cloud Storage does provide REST API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/) in your ***Logic app*** or ***Function app.***

[image]

But my suggestion is you can use the **Azure Function** to do these things. Because the azure Function can be more **flexible** to write your own flow to do the task.

Refer to run your **.exe file in the Azure function**. If you are using  [Local EXE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45348498/run-exe-executable-file-in-azure-function) or using  [Cloud Environment exe](https://demiliani.com/2020/01/17/executing-your-exe-tasks-on-a-cloud-environment-by-using-azure-functions/).

Refer [here](https://www.codit.eu/blog/send-messages-to-google-storage-with-azure-functions/?country_sel=be) for more information